# Getting derived classes to not inherit base class functions

Tags: c++, inheritance

I'm not sure if this is even remotely possible but here it goes:
is it possible for a derived class to NOT inherit a base class function ( without making them private/protected or overriding them an empty definition ) ?
Something like:

```
class base{
public:
virtual int f();
virtual int g();
};

class derived1: public base  //<-- this would inherit f() but not g()
class derived2: public base  //<-- this would inherit g() but not f()
```

Comment: Isn't possible, in that case your base class is not the correct one, when you derive a class you're saying, "hey!, this class is an extension of the base, and IS A base"

Comment: You'll probably need two base classes to inherent from, which may lead to [diamond inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond_problem) if you insist on having the derived classes maintaining some semblance of similarity for a contianer. But honestly, I can't imagine in what scenario anyone would ever want to do what you've described since it's not a very generic approach to doing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it's not. And even if it were, it would be a design flaw.

If `derived1` **is-a** `base`, why shouldn't it inherit all its members? That's what inheritance represents.

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of marking a method as virtual is to get inherited. I don't understand why would you want to mark it virtual but get not inherited. So what is the problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do something,the "thing" should have a purpose.
What you are trying to do defeats the whole idea of virtual function and inheritance in general.
No situation would warrant that type of construct.

And as inheritance is so related to the real world,can a child choose features from his parents.??
I guess not(though it can be useful in this case. :)  )

Answer (score 0):

This actually defies the point of inheritance. It's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just going to chime in on the design concept and cases where this can show up.

I have a base class called Range like so:

```
class Range
{
private:
    int max;
    int min;
    int value;

    virtual void SetMax(int);
    virtual void SetMin(int);
public:
    Range(int max, int min);
    virtual void SetValue(int v);
    virtual int  GetValue() const;
    virtual ~Range();
    Range & operator =(int);
    Range & operator =(const Range &);

};
```

and this base class is used in a Date & Time class we wrote:

```
class Month : public Range
{
public:
    Month();
    Month(int);
    Month(const Month &);
    ~Month();
    Month & operator =(int);
    Month & operator =(const Month &);
    const wchar_t * const AsString() const;
};
```

and one of Month's constructors looks like this:

```
ptiDate::Month::Month(int v):Range(12,1)
{
    SetValue(v);
}
```

but when came time to define the Day class, I originally was going to create a Day::Range base class from which to derive WeekDay and MonthDay classes but felt this created a messy API.  When I tried to encapsulate both the WeekDay and MonthDay, I attempted this:

This is what I tried:

```
class Day : public Range
{
private:
    bool LeapDay;
    int  wday;
    int  mday;
public:
    Day();
    Day(int);
    Day(const Day &);
    ~Day();
    Day & operator =(int);
    Day & operator =(const Day &);
    const wchar_t * const WeekDayAsString() const;
    const wchar_t * const MonthDayAsString() const;

    bool isLeapDay() const;
};
```

and then my dilemma: I no longer wanted to inherit the Range SetMax and SetMin methods due to the ambiguity.  I.E. Am I setting Max days of the week or days of the month... Well, the days of the week are fixed so Day::Range::max and Day::Range::min refer to the days of the month and day of the week is just figured out....

I would be curious how others would have designed this.

Giving rise to:

```
Date Today(Month(3), Day(19), Year(2012));
```

An idea inspired by Scott Meyers, Effective C++ (3rd Ed), page 80 [Item 18]